# Header Multiple Redirects in php

Tags: php, redirect, header

How to have 4 header redirects?

I have a form, after is submitted is verified, if the form is not completed correctly will be redirected to error.php, if is okay will be redirected to success.php. I have this code and work perfectly:

```
@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

header("Location: success.php");
}
else
{
header("Location: error.php");
}
```

This one with 3 redirects work perfectly:

@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

```
if(isset($_GET['group'])){
    $group=trim($_GET["group"]);
}
if (strtolower(substr($group,0,1)) == '1'){
     header('Location: group1.php');
}elseif (strtolower(substr($group,0,1))=='2'){
     header('Location: group2.php');
}else{
     header('Location: anothergroup.php');
}
```

For 4 redirects I tried this but not working:

```
if(isset($_POST["group"])){
    $group=trim($_POST["group"]);
}
if (strtolower(substr($group,0,1)) == '1'){
     header("Location: group1.php");
}elseif (strtolower(substr($group,0,1))=='2'){
     header("Location: group2.php");
}elseif{
     header("Location: anothergroup.php");
}
else
{
header("Location: error.php");
}
```

How to get this last code working?

Comment: You need to add a condition to your last "elseif". Like this: `...elseif(strtolower(substr($group,0,1))=='3')...`

Comment: Can you please explain the difference in what you are wanting to happen and what is actually happening. Just looking at the code, your second elseif doesn't have any (condition). This is probably causing unexpected results.

Comment: My form has a input for Group number. I want if the person is in group 1 to be redirected to group1.php, if is in group 2 to be redirected to group2.php, if is in any other group to be redirected to anothergroup.php, and if the form has errors to be redirected to error.php. So what condition to add to be redirected to anothergroup.php is the person put in any number that isn't 1 or 2

Comment: Anybody know how to resolve this ?